# Access denied to database using Doctrine with Symfony 5.3

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a big issue with Doctrine using Symfony 5.3 I've been trying to solve for 2 days now...

I've installed Doctrine bundle following Symfony documentation and I configured my `.env` file with `DATABASE_URL` environment variable like this: `postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/<my_db>?serverVersion=11.2&charset=utf8`.

I was able to create my database, execute my migrations, and everything works well when I run console commands like `php bin/console dbal:run-sql` for instance. But when I try to flush an entity in my controller, I systematically get a denied access error:

```
php-fpm | NOTICE: PHP message: [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
php-fpm |   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
php-fpm |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/PostgreSQL/ExceptionConverter.php line 73
```

Something weird I've noticed: if i dump `$entityManager->getConnection()->getParams()` just before executing my request in my controller, I get:

```
 array:11 [
  "url" => "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
  "driver" => "pdo_pgsql"
  "host" => "127.0.0.1"
  "port" => 5432
  "user" => "db_user"
  "password" => "db_password"
  "driverOptions" => []
  "defaultTableOptions" => []
  "dbname" => "db_name"
  "serverVersion" => "13"
  "charset" => "utf8"
]
```

And if I add the following lines, everything works again:

```
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection([
            'url' => 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/<my_db>?serverVersion=11.2&charset=utf8'
        ]);
        $conn->executeQuery("<MY_SQL_QUERY>");
```

It's like my `.env` file or `doctrine.yaml` config file were not taken into account at all.

Here is my `doctrine.yaml` config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        schema_filter: /^(?!.*my_schema).*/

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
        driver:   pdo_pgsql
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Of course `pgsql` and `pdo_pgsql` modules are both enabled in my PHP container.

Does anybody have an idea or already faced this issue?

Tks!

**EDIT**

Ok, so here is an extract of my docker-compose.yaml file, defining my php service:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  php-fpm:
    image: XXX/api:dev
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

If I add:

```
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/<my_db>?serverVersion=11.2&charset=utf8"
```

it works! I can't understand anything...

Comment: Do you have a `.env.local` file as well ?

Comment: @DylanKas no I don't :/

Comment: And are you sure your postgre server run on localhost with port 5432 ?

Comment: @DylanKas yes, and If I execute a query through `bin/console` or if I create a new connection with the same url I defined in my `.env` inside my controller, everything works perfectly. So I don't think there is anything to do with my pgsql server or how my postgres docker container is configured.

Comment: What is the output of `php bin/console debug:config doctrine`? And are there any other `.env.*****` files such as `.env.dev` or separate `doctrine:` configuration reference in the `config/packages/dev` directory? Otherwise usage of `SetEnv ` occurring in your platform such as from PHP-FPM or Apache/nginx?

Comment: What if you run a shell in the PHP container and run `echo $DATABASE_URL` and `cat /etc/hosts`?